Calculated column adding a date column with a number column, using only working days (excludes Saturdays & Sundays/weekends)
I have a calculated column resulting in a date [titled Target Date of Bid] and another calculated column resulting in a number [Minimum # of days in the market] that I'm trying to add together.  However, the result needs to be working days only (excludes Saturdays & Sundays/weekends). What's the best formula for this?
Tried this, but it's resulting in an error:
=([Target Date of Bid]+[Min # of Days in Market] + IF (WEEKDAY([Target Date of Bid],3)<5,1+FLOOR(([Min # of Days in Market]-6+WEEKDAY([Target Date of Bid],3))/5,1)*2,7-WEEKDAY([Target Date of Bid],2)+FLOOR(([Min # of Days in Market]-1)/2,1)*2))


Try this example:
=IF(WEEKDAY([Finish Date]-(FLOOR([No of Days]/5,1)*7+MOD([No of Days],5)-1))=1,[Finish Date]-(FLOOR([No of Days]/5,1)*7+MOD([No of Days],5)-1)-2,IF(WEEKDAY([Finish Date]-(FLOOR([No of Days]/5,1)*7+MOD([No of Days],5)-1))=7,[Finish Date]-(FLOOR([No of Days]/5,1)*7+MOD([No of Days],5)-1)-1,[Finish Date]-(FLOOR([No of Days]/5,1)*7+MOD([No of Days],5)-1)))

